laplace or fourier transformation with additional log factors
I have an expression that looks like
$$F(x) = \int_0^\infty da\, db\, dc\, f(a)\,g(b)\,h(c)\,\delta(x-a-b-c)\,.$$
Such delta function convolution is particularly simple to think about from the Laplace (or Fourier) space. In particular, I can simplify the convolution through the transform as
$$\tilde{F}(s) = \int_0^\infty dx e^{-i s x} F(x)= \tilde{f}(s)\,\tilde{g}(s)\,\tilde{h}(s)\,.$$
Therefore, $$F(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{2\pi} \tilde{F}(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{2\pi} \tilde{f}(s)\,\tilde{g}(s)\,\tilde{h}(s).$$
I'm curious now whether there's a similar factorized expression for $F(x) \ln^n x$ in the transformed space. The log interrupts the factorization as $\ln^n x = \ln^n (a+b+c)$ does not factorize nicely.
But I thought this might still be possible since $$\ln^n x = (\partial/\partial \alpha)^n x^\alpha|_{\alpha=0}$$
and $$x^\alpha = (a+b+c)^\alpha = \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=\alpha}\binom{\alpha}{k_1, k_2, k_3} a^{k_1}b^{k_2}c^{k_3}.$$
Then each term has factorized expression involving $a$, $b$, and $c$, allowing one to factorize the transformation.
What I'm unsure are

Since multinomial expansion is just for $\alpha$ being non-negative 'integer', I would need an analytical continuation of this expression instead. Is there a nice integral representation for my purpose?

I also need to take the derivatives with respect to $\alpha$ then set $\alpha$ to zero at the end. Can my final expression still written in a nice form in the end?


Thanks!

Something seems amiss here, I’ll have a second look later.

Thanks a lot. Would appreciate your thoughts!

I think your question is misguided since $$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \delta(x-a-b-c), f(a) , da=f(x-b-c), \theta(x-b-c)$$ for example. Or did you really mean $$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \left(\int\limits_0^{\infty} \left(\int\limits_0^{\infty} f(a), g(b), h(c), \delta(x-a), \delta(x-b), \delta(x-c), , da\right) , db\right) , dc=\left(\int\limits_0^{\infty} f(a) \delta(x-a) , da\right) \left(\int\limits_0^{\infty} g(b) \delta(x-b) , db\right) \int\limits_0^{\infty} h(c) \delta(x-c) , dc\=f(x), g(x), h(x), \theta(x)$$ which is a product where the Fourier transform is a convolution?

I do not mean the second equation. I just mean that if I have the convolution of the first equation you wrote down (actually with b and c integration as well), then it turns into a product when you carry out the fourier transformation. That is, it turns into a product of individual fourier transform

This product form is no longer naively possible if I multiply overall "ln(x)". However, it is possible for x^n with integer n, since x^n = (a+b+c)^n can be written in terms of a^k1 b^k2 c^k3, where k1+k2+k3 = n. My question is whether ln(x) can also be written as apparently factorizable form, given that x^n and ln(x) are related by derivatives (though one needs analytic continuation)

Why did you define $F(x)$ as $$F(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty da, db, dc, f(a), g(b), h(c),\delta(x-a-b-c)\tag{1}$$ instead of as $$F(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty da, db, f(a), g(b), \delta(x-a-b)\tag{2}$$ for example? Is there anything special about formula (1) above that doesn't also apply to formula (2) above? If not, it seems to me it'd be simpler to answer your question in the context of formula (2) above.

It seems to me the convergence of the convolution is dependent on the characteristics of $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$. You never specified the characteristics of these functions in the first place, and therefore you have not excluded the inclusion of a $\log^n(x)$ factor in their definitions in the first place. I believe the issue of convergence is independent of whether the convolution is evaluated using the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ or evaluated using the normal definition of convolution.

I don't believe the result has anything to do with factorization of $\log^n(a+b+c)$. The convolution theorem applies under suitable conditions. Assuming the convolution theorem is valid for $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ then validity of the convolution theorem for $f_n(x)=f(x)\, \log^n(x)$, $g_n(x)=g(x)\, \log^n(x)$, and $h_n(x)=h(x)\, \log^n(x)$ is perhaps dependent on the definitions of $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$. Perhaps for different definitions of these functions multiplying them by $\log^n(x)$ could either meet or violate the suitable conditions required for the convolution theorem.

Even when the convolution theorem applies theoretically to the convolution of $f_n(x)=f(x)\, \log^n(x)$, $g_n(x)=g(x)\, \log^n(x)$, and $h_n(x)=h(x)\, \log^n(x)$, evaluating the convolution and Fourier transforms related to the convolution theorem may be difficult practically.

I believe this question can be addressed without loss of generality in the simpler context of
$$F(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty g(b) \int\limits_0^\infty f(a)\, \delta(x-a-b) \, da \, db\tag{1}$$
which reduces the complexity by avoiding the necessity of evaluating a second convolution involving $\log^n(x)$.

Consider the rectangle functions
$$f(x)=\Pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0<x<1 \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$
and
$$g(x)=\Pi\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1<x<2 \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}$$
where
$$F(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty g(b) \int\limits_0^\infty f(a)\, \delta(x-a-b) \, da \, db=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 x-1 & 1<x\leq 2 \\
 3-x & 2<x<3 \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}$$
is their convolution.

Note the Fourier transforms
$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\, e^{-2 i \pi x \omega} \, dx=\frac{e^{-i \pi \omega} \sin(\pi \omega)}{\pi \omega}\tag{5}$$
and
$$\hat{g}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[g(x)](\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} g(x)\, e^{-2 i \pi x \omega} \, dx=\frac{e^{-3 i \pi \omega} \sin(\pi \omega)}{\pi \omega}\tag{6}$$
are consistent with the Fourier transform
$$\hat{F}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[F(x)](\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} F(x)\, e^{-2 i \pi x \omega} \, dx=\frac{e^{-4 i \pi \omega} \sin^2(\pi \omega)}{\pi^2 \omega^2}\tag{7}$$
since $\hat{F}(\omega)=\hat{f}(\omega)\, \hat{g}(\omega)$ as predicted by the convolution theorem.

Now consider the functions
$$f_1(x)=f(x) \log(x)\tag{8}$$
and
$$g_1(x)=g(x) \log(x)\tag{9}$$
where
$$F_1(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty g_1(b) \int\limits_0^\infty f_1(a)\, \delta(x-a-b) \, da \, db\\=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 -x \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+2 x+x (-\log(x))+\log(x-1) (-x+x \log(x)+1)-2 & 1<x\leq 2 \\
 -x \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+x \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x-2}{x}\right)+x \log\left(x^2-3 x+2\right)-2 x-\log (4 (x-1))+\log(x-2) (-x \log(x)-2+\log(4))+6 & 2<x<3 \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{10}$$
is their convolution.

I haven't been able to directly evaluate the Fourier transform
$$\hat{F}_1(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[F_1(x)](\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} F_1(x)\, e^{-2 i \pi x \omega} \, dx\tag{11}$$
of $F_1(x)$ defined in formula (10) above, but assuming the convolution theorem the Fourier transforms
$$\hat{f}_1(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[f_1(x)](\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} f_1(x)\, e^{-2 i \pi x \omega} \, dx=\frac{i\, (-\text{Ci}(2 \pi \omega)+i\, \text{Si}(2 \pi \omega)+\log(2 \pi \omega)+\gamma)}{2 \pi \omega}\tag{12}$$
and
$$\hat{g}_1(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[g_1(x)](\omega)=\int_0^{\infty} g_1(x)\, e^{-2 i \pi x \omega} \, dx=\frac{i e^{-4 i \pi \omega} \left(e^{4 i \pi \omega} (E_1(4 i \pi \omega)-E_1(2 i \pi \omega))-e^{2 i \pi \omega} \left(\log (2 i \omega )+\log\left(-\frac{i}{2 \omega}\right)\right)+\log(4 i \omega)+\log\left(-\frac{i}{2 \omega}\right)\right)}{2 \pi \omega}\tag{13}$$
lead to
$$\hat{F}_1(\omega)=\hat{f}_1(\omega)\, \hat{g}_1(\omega)=-\frac{e^{-4 i \pi \omega}}{4 \pi^2 \omega^2} (-\text{Ci}(2 \pi \omega)+i\, \text{Si}(2 \pi \omega)+\log(2 \pi \omega)+\gamma)\\ \left(e^{4 i \pi \omega} (E_1(4 i \pi \omega)-E_1(2 i \pi \omega))-e^{2 i \pi \omega} \left(\log(2 i \omega)+\log\left(-\frac{i}{2 \omega}\right)\right)+\log(4 i \omega)+\log\left(-\frac{i}{2 \omega}\right)\right)\tag{14}$$
as the Fourier transform of $F_1(x)$.

Figures (1) and (2) below illustrate the Fourier transform integral defined in formula (11) above evaluated via numeric integration in orange overlaid on $\hat{F}_1(\omega)$ defined in formula (14) above in blue which seems to confirm the convolution theorem is valid for the convolution $F_1(x)$ defined in formula (10) above (which is expected since $F_1(x)$ is a function with compact support on the interval $0<x<3$).


Figure (1): Illustration of real parts of formulas (11) and (14) above in orange and blue where formula (11) is evaluated using numeric integration


Figure (2): Illustration of imaginary parts of formulas (11) and (14) above in orange and blue where formula (11) is evaluated using numeric integration
Update:
Based on the comments below, it seems the question was about
$$F_n(x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty} g(b) \int\limits_0^{\infty} f(a)\, \log^n(x)\, \delta(x-a-b) \, da \, db\tag{15}$$
rather than
$$F_n(x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty} g(b)\, \log^n(b) \int\limits_0^{\infty} f(a)\, \log^n(a)\, \delta(x-a-b) \, da \, db\tag{16}.$$

Since $\log^n(x)$ is not a function of $a$ or $b$ it can be removed from the nested integral in formula (15) above and therefore
$$F_n(x)=\log^n(x) \int\limits_0^{\infty} g(b) \int\limits_0^{\infty} f(a)\, \delta(x-a-b) \, da \, db=F_0(x)\, \log^n(x)\tag{17}$$
is the product of two functions $F_0(x)$ and $g(x)=\log^n(x)$. The Fourier transform of the product $F_n(x)=F_0(x)\, g(x)=F_0(x)\, \log^n(x)$ is the convolution
$$\hat{F}_n(\omega)=[\hat{F_0}(\xi) * \hat{g}(\xi)](\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{F_0}(\xi)\, \hat{g}(\omega-\xi) \, d\xi$$
where $\hat{F_0}(\omega)$, $\hat{g}(\omega)$, and $\hat{F_n}(\omega)$ are the Fourier transforms $F_0(x)$, $g(x)=\log^n(x)$, and $F_n(x)=F_0(x)\, g(x)=F_0(x)\, \log^n(x)$. So, the Fourier transform $\hat{F}_n(\omega)$ is the convolution of two Fourier transforms rather than the product of two Fourier transforms, and this has nothing to do with factorization of $\log^n(a+b)$.

Thanks a lot for the answer. But I think there's a confusion here. I was not asking about
$$F_1(x)=\int_0^{\infty} g(b) \log(b) \int_0^{\infty} f(a) \log(a) \delta(x-a-b) d a d b$$, but rather
$$F_n(x)=\int_0^{\infty} g(b) \int_0^{\infty} f(a) \log^n(x) \delta(x-a-b) d a d b$$
That is, if I assume the convolution theorem applies well for $\hat{F}_0(\omega)=\hat{f}(\omega) \hat{g}(\omega)$, then can I also rewrite $\hat{F}_n(\omega)$ into a product of two Fourier transforms?

This was the reason why I made efforts to rewrite $ \log^n(x)$ into a factorized form, separating it into one function that depends solely on 'a' and another that depends only on 'b'
